# djangoでウェブサイトが立ち上げれない

Tags: python, django

djangoでプロジェクトを作成し`allow host =['*']`にしてterminalで`python manage.py runserver`と打ち送られてくるリンクにアクセスしたんですけど、

```
This site can’t provide a secure connection127.0.0.1 sent an invalid response.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

と出ます。ちなみにgoogle chromeです。
昨日まではできていたdjangoのprojectでもだめでした。

Comment: 立ち上がらないというよりも、SSL 関連でブラウザがブロックしているように見えます。 / 立ち上げはローカルのPC上で実行されているのでしょうか？実行環境をもう少し具体的に書いておくと回答のヒントになるかもしれません。

Comment: `http://127.0.0.1:8000` と生の HTTP で接続すべき開発サーバに対して、 `https://127.0.0.1:8000` として、 **HTTP"S"** の暗号化を期待して接続してしまっている場合のエラーかと思います。 URL の先頭部分は適切ですか？ 意図的に URL を `https://` で書き始めていないにも関わらずそのエラーが表示されるようであれば、何らかの理由で 127.0.0.1 が HSTS に記憶され、強制的に HTTPS へとリダイレクトされているのかもしれません。その場合、ブラウザにそれを忘れさせる必要が有ると思われます。